# memory allocation for pointer same in both cases?

Tags: c

Does memory allocation for pointer is same in both scenarios

```
struct_datatype * p=NULL;

struct_datatype * p=malloc;
```

apart from memory allocation from stack and heap ??

Comment: I don't understand the question. The second line probably needs an explicit cast (pointer to a function => pointer to `struct_datatype`)

Comment: Are you asking about the size of the pointer? The total amount of memory taken?

Comment: The first line allocates nothing more on the stack than the second one does (even if you _do_ call `malloc`)

Comment: @JanDvorak: I suspect the OP is just missing `(...)` after the `malloc` ...

Comment: The second line is suspect - is it intentionally making a pointer to the malloc function?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think perhaps your third response is the answer. The malloc goes on the heap, and the size of the pointer on the stack is the same regardless. There may be some kind of compiler optimization to discriminate between a far pointer and near pointer.

Comment: Neither of these allocates memory.

Comment: @NPE if the `malloc` is called, memory does get allocated.

Comment: @JanDvorak: There are no parentheses and therefore no function call there. I think the OP ought to invest a little more effort into preparing their question.

Comment: sorry for question not being clear. thanks for all. I know about typecasting the memory allocate using malloc. I mean to ask. i am passing ptr variable to API. where the API fills the structure and returns back. my doubt is in both cases my structure is getting filled. struct_datatype * p=NULL does where it points ? how much memory gets nullified ? entire size of structure ?

Comment: @NPE Malloc has parameters, i kept just like that becoz without parameters it fails.

Comment: @david:Assigning *p=NULL points to nothing, whereas, *p=some valid address points to some usable memory. Assigning a pointer to NULL and Nullifying the memory are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear what you are asking about.

`struct_datatype * p=NULL;`
No memory has been assigned to `p`. It points to no allocated memory.

`struct_datatype * p=malloc();`
Some memory might have been allocated and the address of the memory allocated has been assigned to `p`. If malloc failed NULL would have been assigned to `p`.

NOTE: sizeof `p` will be sizeof `struct_datatype*` for both the cases.

NOTE: The pointer variable `p` will have been assigned memory in the *stack* which is sizeof `struct_datatype*` in both the cases during compile time. The address stored in pointer `p` might be pointing to any valid memory address accessible in user address space. In the `NULL` case no address is assigned( and NULL is not user accessible address) but when you do `malloc`(if successful) the address of the memory allocated will be assigned to the pointer `p` from the *heap* space else again it will be assigned to NULL.

Comment: sorry for the question not being clear. I know about the type casting the malloc pointers. my doubt is both cases if we pass this pointer variable to some API. according to API its need to return the data filled in structure. So in both cases my structure is filled with data. does it could create any problem if dont allocate memory?

Comment: Yes. If in the API, the structure pointer is accessed and if the pointer assigned to NULL, this does mean that there's no memory to access using the pointer variable.So, It might cause a seg-fault, a zero-exception or such depending on compiler and platform. I suggest, in the API before accessing the pointer variable and trying to fill in data into the memory allocated by the pointer, do a NULL-check on the pointer itself.

Comment: Thanks askmish for reply.fine askmish.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the errors. I meant `sizeof(struct_datatype*)` based on the context. EDITing.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the pointer is initialized to point to address 0, so if you access the data the pointer points to, you get a 0-pointer exception, because the pointer does not point to a accessible memory-location.

In the second case, p=(struct_datatype *)malloc (sizeof (struct_datatype)); memory is allocated and assigned to the pointer, so you can access that memory thru p, e.g. if x is a int-field in your struct, you can set this x by `p->x=123`